# Check if current row cell date is in the past

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to access numerous rows in a loop to check if the END DATE (in Column C) is in the past.

If the END DATE is in the past I want to check if Column M contains the string "Cancel", if it doesn't I want to write "cancel" to column M, before moving to the next row.

Comment: You can check if END DATE < NOW()

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to go about it, but this macro should look at each value in the column (the macro stops if it reaches a blank cell) and checks if it is less than the system date. If the date is less, it assigns the value "Cancel" to the cell in Column M in the same row.

```
Sub checkDate()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1 'Starts on row one.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Do While .Range("C" & x).Value <> "" 'Checks each row in Column C until it reaches an empty row. Could be replaced with a For statement.
            If .Range("C" & x).Value < Date Then
                .Range("M" & x).Value = "Cancel"
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```